# Django Rest Framework method in action decorator needs be specified in class http_method_names

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

DRF version is 3.11.2

I was working on some existing code to add an extra "delete" action to a viewset, but I got `405 Method not allowed`, consider the following made up example

```py
class UserViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    ....
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    http_method_names = ['get', 'post']

    @action(detail=True, method=['delete'])
    def delete_profile(self, request, pk=None)
        Profile.objects.get(user=pk).delete()
        ....
```

Like I said, when I make a delete method call to `/user/123/delete_profile`, I get `405 Method not allowed`, however, if I add `delete` to `http_method_names` as below, it works fine.

```py
class UserViewSet(ViewSet):
    ....
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    http_method_names = ['get', 'post', 'delete']

    @action(detail=True, method=['delete'])
    def delete_profile(self, request, pk=None)
        Profile.objects.get(user=pk).delete()
        ....
```

But this is not ideal as I don't want to allow "delete" operation on the User, whilst I can overwrite the `delete`/`destroy` method on the viewset to avoid user being deleted, this is not very elegant.

So the question is, is this a bug or by design? By design I mean the extra actions decorated by `@action` suppose to be manipulating the same model defined in the `ModelViewSet` (in this case User and not Profile)?

Comment: Why don't you override destroy method that you could inherit from ViewSet class, and then apply a specific permission maybe using get_permission method ?

Comment: Cos like I said, it's not elegant.

Comment: Since you are using a `ViewSet` class. If you don't implement the `destroy` method, it should return HTTP 405 by default. No need to restrict `http_method_names`.

Comment: Sorry I actually meant ModelViewSet not ViewSet, updated my question to reflect that.

Comment: You can use [`generics.GenericViewSet`](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/#genericviewset) with [mixins](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#mixins) to implement only the methods that you want. See [`ModelViewSet`](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/viewsets.py#L235) source code for examples.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is with setting the `http_method_names` attribute to the ModelViewSet. since you have set it to only `get` and `post` , other methods ( `put`, `patch`, `delete`) will not work on the class. either you have to add the `delete` method to `http_method_names` attribute or remove the whole attribute to fix this as shown below.

```
class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
    queryset = User.objects.all()

    @action(detail=True, methods=['delete'])
    def delete_profile(self, request, pk=None):
        Profile.objects.get(user=pk).delete()
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)
```

Also if you dont want other methods than `get`,`post`,`delete` to work, why not use mixins ?

**Update :**
if you dont want the delete method to work on the main viewset, just override it as shown.

```
 class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
    queryset = User.objects.all() 

    @action(detail=True, methods=['delete'])
    def delete_profile(self, request, pk=None):
         ....

    def destroy(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_405_METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED)
```

Comment: I was just editing some existing code, there are a lot more code in the class that I don't want to refactor. I don't want the "delete" to work for the main viewset.

Comment: updated the answer, please check if this is what you want to achieve

Comment: Thanks for trying to help, but like I mentioned in my question, this is already a non-ideal known solution, I want to avoid doing this.

Comment: i see. No problem. this was the best i could think of. Any reason why this is considered non-ideal?

Comment: I see non-ideal because the `delete` method in `http_method_names` is unwanted, that is problem 1, and to override `destroy` method to overcome problem 1, that's problem 2. Like a workaround on top of another workaround.

Comment: problem1 is eliminated by removing the whole `http_method_names` (if all the crud operations are needed since you are using modelviewset). problem 2 is not for overcoming problem1, bcs in modelviewset all the crud operations are prebuilt, so anyhow we need to override if we dont want/alter any operation. mixins will not be an option since you dont want to refactor